# Wordpress Yelp Review Ticker Plugin

Tags: wordpress

I made this plugin to show reviews from yelp from my business, it is my first attempt and it works, but I'd like to share it with everyone.
When I add my settings on the code it works the way it is supposed to. But when I made the admin interface so people can use their own API keys and change the look to their best fitting, it won't "save" the settings and will not work.
I am hoping someone could shed some light and help me out so I can share the code/plugin.
(by the way this is my first attempt to coding)

yelprt.php

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:  Yelp Reviews Ticker
Plugin URI:   http://www.google.com/
Description:  Yelp Reviews Ticker
Version:      0.1
Author:       Flavio
Author URI:   http://www.google.com/    
*/
    function yelp_rt_widget($args, $widget_args = 1) {

        extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );
        if ( is_numeric($widget_args) )
            $widget_args = array( 'number' => $widget_args );
        $widget_args = wp_parse_args( $widget_args, array( 'number' => -1 ) );
        extract( $widget_args, EXTR_SKIP );

        $options = get_option('yelprt_widget');
        if ( !isset($options[$number]) ) 
        return;

        $title = $options[$number]['title'];        // single value
        $speed = $options[$number]['speed'];
        $pause = $options[$number]['pause'];
        $showitems = $options[$number]['showitems'];
        $animation = $options[$number]['animation'];
        $mousepause = $options[$number]['mousepause'];
        //$height = $options[$number]['height'];
        $direction = $options[$number]['direction'];
        $yrtunsigned_url = $options[$number]['unsigned_url'];
        $yrtconsumer_key = $options[$number]['consumer_key'];
        $yrtconsumer_secret = $options[$number]['consumer_secret'];
        $yrttoken = $options[$number]['token'];
        $yrttoken_secret = $options[$number]['token_secret'];

        echo $before_widget; // start widget display code 
?><h2><?=$title?></h2><?php
//print $yrtunsigned_url;
//echo $options[$number]['unsigned_url'];

//******MY ADDITION     
// From http://non-diligent.com/articles/yelp-apiv2-php-example/
//

// Enter the path that the oauth library is in relation to the php file
//require_once ('lib/OAuth.php');
$unsigned_url = $options[$number]['unsigned_url'];
$consumer_key = $options[$number]['consumer_key'];
$consumer_secret = $options[$number]['consumer_secret'];
$token = $options[$number]['token'];
$token_secret = $options[$number]['token_secret'];


require_once ('lib/OAuth.php');
// Token object built using the OAuth library
$token = new OAuthToken($token, $token_secret);
//$token = new OAuthToken($yrttoken, $yrttoken_secret);

// Consumer object built using the OAuth library
$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
//$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($yrtconsumer_key, $yrtconsumer_secret);

// Yelp uses HMAC SHA1 encoding
$signature_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();

// Build OAuth Request using the OAuth PHP library. Uses the consumer and token object created above.
$oauthrequest = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $token, 'GET', $unsigned_url);
//$oauthrequest = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $token, 'GET', $yrtunsigned_url);

// Sign the request
$oauthrequest->sign_request($signature_method, $consumer, $token);
//$oauthrequest->sign_request($signature_method, $yrtconsumer, $yrttoken);

// Get the signed URL
$signed_url = $oauthrequest->to_url();

// Send Yelp API Call
$ch = curl_init($signed_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch); // Yelp response
curl_close($ch);

// Handle Yelp response data
$response = json_decode($data);

$arr = (array) $response;

if(is_array($arr['reviews'])){
    echo    "<div id='yelprt'>";
    echo    "<ul id='list'>";
    foreach($arr['reviews'] as $review){
        echo "<li><div id='yelprt_table'>\n";
        echo "  <div class='row'>\n";
        echo "    <span class='yelprt_cell2'>\n";
        echo "      <img src='" . $review->user->image_url . "' width='60px'/>\n";
        echo "      <br />" . $review->user->name . "\n";
        echo "      <br /><img src='" . $review->rating_image_small_url . "'/>\n";
        echo "  </span>\n";
        echo "    <span class='yelprt_cell1'>\n";
        echo "      " . $review->excerpt . "\n";
        echo "      <br />\n";
        echo "          <span class='yelprt_smalltxt'>" . gmdate("m/d/Y", $review->time_created) . " more at <a href='".$yrtunsigned_url."'><img src='http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/14f29ad24935/map/miniMapLogo.png'/></a></span>\n";
        echo "  </span>\n";
        echo "  </div>\n";
        echo " </div></li>\n";
    }
    echo    "</div>";
}

    echo $after_widget; // end widget display code

}


    function yelp_rt_widget_control($widget_args) {

        global $wp_registered_widgets;
        static $updated = false;

        if ( is_numeric($widget_args) )
            $widget_args = array( 'number' => $widget_args );           
        $widget_args = wp_parse_args( $widget_args, array( 'number' => -1 ) );
        extract( $widget_args, EXTR_SKIP );

        $options = get_option('yelprt_widget');

        if ( !is_array($options) )  
            $options = array();

        if ( !$updated && !empty($_POST['sidebar']) ) {

            $sidebar = (string) $_POST['sidebar'];  
            $sidebars_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();

            if ( isset($sidebars_widgets[$sidebar]) )
                $this_sidebar =& $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar];
            else
                $this_sidebar = array();

            foreach ( (array) $this_sidebar as $_widget_id ) {
                if ( 'yelp_rt_widget' == $wp_registered_widgets[$_widget_id]['callback'] && isset($wp_registered_widgets[$_widget_id]['params'][0]['number']) ) {
                    $widget_number = $wp_registered_widgets[$_widget_id]['params'][0]['number'];
                    if ( !in_array( "yelp-rt-$widget_number", $_POST['widget-id'] ) ) // the widget has been removed.
                        unset($options[$widget_number]);
                }
            }

            foreach ( (array) $_POST['yelp-rt'] as $widget_number => $yelprt_widget ) {
                if ( !isset($yelprt_widget['title']) && isset($options[$widget_number]) ) // user clicked cancel
                    continue;

                $title = strip_tags(stripslashes($yelprt_widget['title']));
                $speed = $yelprt_widget['speed_value'];
                $pause = $yelprt_widget['pause_value'];
                $showitems = $yelprt_widget['showitems_value'];
                $animation = $yelprt_widget['animation_value'];
                $mousepause = $yelprt_widget['mousepause_value'];
                //$height = $yelprt_widget['height_value'];
                $direction = $yelprt_widget['direction_value'];
                $yrtunsigned_url = $yelprt_widget['unsigned_url_value'];
                $yrtconsumer_key = $yelprt_widget['consumer_key_value'];
                $yrtconsumer_secret = $yelprt_widget['consumer_secret_value'];
                $yrttoken = $yelprt_widget['token_value'];
                $yrttoken_secret = $yelprt_widget['token_secret_value'];
                // Pact the values into an array
                $options[$widget_number] = compact( 'title', 'speed', 'pause', 'showitems', 'animation', 'mousepause', 'direction', 'unsigned_url', 'consumer_key', 'consumer_secret', 'token', 'token_secret' );
            }

            update_option('yelprt_widget', $options);
            $updated = true;
        }

        if ( -1 == $number ) { // if it's the first time and there are no existing values

            $title = 'Reviews';
            $speed = '2500';
            $pause = '6000';
            $showitems = '2';
            $animation = 'fade';
            $mousepause = 'true';
            //$height = '';
            $direction = 'up';
            $yrtunsigned_url = '';
            $yrtconsumer_key = '';
            $yrtconsumer_secret = '';
            $yrttoken = '';
            $yrttoken_secret = '';
            $yrtnumber = '%i%';

        } else { // otherwise get the existing values

            $title = $options[$number]['title'];
            $speed = $options[$number]['speed'];
            $pause = $options[$number]['pause'];
            $showitems = $options[$number]['showitems'];
            $animation = $options[$number]['animation'];
            $mousepause = $options[$number]['mousepause'];
            //$height = $options[$number]['height'];
            $direction = $options[$number]['direction'];
            $yrtunsigned_url = $options[$number]['unsigned_url'];
            $yrtconsumer_key = $options[$number]['consumer_key'];
            $yrtconsumer_secret = $options[$number]['consumer_secret'];
            $yrttoken = $options[$number]['token'];
            $yrttoken_secret = $options[$number]['token_secret'];
        }

        print_r($options[$number]);

    ?>
    <p><label>Widget Title</label><br /><input id="title_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="yelp-rt[<?php echo $number; ?>][title]" type="text" value="<?=$title?>" /></p>
    <p><label>Speed</label><br /><input id="speed_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="yelp-rt[<?php echo $number; ?>][speed_value]" type="text" value="<?=$speed?>" /></p>
    <p><label>Pause</label><br /><input id="pause_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="yelp-rt[<?php echo $number; ?>][pause_value]" type="text" value="<?=$pause?>" /></p>
    <p><label>Show Items</label><br /><input id="showitems_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="yelp-rt[<?php echo $number; ?>][showitems_value]" type="text" value="<?=$showitems?>" /></p>

    <p>
        <label>Fade</label><br />
        Yes <input id="animation_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="yelp-rt[<?php echo $number; ?>][animation_value]" type="radio" <?php if($animation == 'fade') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="fade" />
        No <input id="animation_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="yelp-rt[<?php echo $number; ?>][animation_value]" type="radio" <?php if($animation == '') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Mousepause</label><br />
        Yes <input id="mousepause_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="yelp-rt[<?php echo $number; ?>][mousepause_value]" type="radio" <?php if($mousepause == 'true') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="true" />
        No <input id="mousepause_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="yelp-rt[<?php echo $number; ?>][mousepause_value]" type="radio" <?php if($mousepause == 'false') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="false" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Direction</label><br />
        Up <input id="direction_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="yelp-rt[<?php echo $number; ?>][direction_value]" type="radio" <?php if($direction == 'up') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="up" />
        Down <input id="direction_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="yelp-rt[<?php echo $number; ?>][direction_value]" type="radio" <?php if($direction == 'down') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="down" />
    </p>
    <p><label>Business URL</label><br /><input id="unsigned_url_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="yelp-rt[<?php echo $number; ?>][unsigned_url_value]" type="text" value="<?=$yrtunsigned_url?>" /></p>
    <p><label>Consumer Key</label><br /><input id="consumer_key_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="yelp-rt[<?php echo $number; ?>][consumer_key_value]" type="text" value="<?=$yrtconsumer_key?>" /></p>
    <p><label>Consumer Secret</label><br /><input id="consumer_secret_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="yelp-rt[<?php echo $number; ?>][consumer_secret_value]" type="text" value="<?=$yrtconsumer_secret?>" /></p>
    <p><label>Token</label><br /><input id="token_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="yelp-rt[<?php echo $number; ?>][token_value]" type="text" value="<?=$yrttoken?>" /></p>
    <p><label>Token Secret</label><br /><input id="token_secret_value_<?php echo $number; ?>" name="yelp-rt[<?php echo $number; ?>][token_secret_value]" type="text" value="<?=$yrttoken_secret?>" /></p>

    <input type="hidden" name="yelp-rt[<?php echo $number; ?>][submit]" value="1" />

    <?php
    }


    function yelp_rt_widget_register() {
        if ( !$options = get_option('yelprt_widget') )
            $options = array();
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'yelprt_widget', 'description' => __('Yelp Reviews Ticker'));
        $control_ops = array('width' => 400, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'yelp-rt');
        $name = __('Yelp Reviews Ticker Widget');

        $id = false;
        foreach ( (array) array_keys($options) as $o ) {

            if ( !isset( $options[$o]['title'] ) )
                continue;

            $id = "yelp-rt-$o";
            wp_register_sidebar_widget($id, $name, 'yelp_rt_widget', $widget_ops, array( 'number' => $o ));
            wp_register_widget_control($id, $name, 'yelp_rt_widget_control', $control_ops, array( 'number' => $o ));
        }

        if ( !$id ) {
            wp_register_sidebar_widget( 'yelp-rt-1', $name, 'yelp_rt_widget', $widget_ops, array( 'number' => -1 ) );
            wp_register_widget_control( 'yelp-rt-1', $name, 'yelp_rt_widget_control', $control_ops, array( 'number' => -1 ) );
        }
    }

add_action('init', yelp_rt_widget_register, 1);
//add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("yelprt_widget");') );
add_action('wp_head', 'yelprt_head');
    function yelprt_head($widget_args) {

        global $wp_registered_widgets;
        static $updated = false;

        if ( is_numeric($widget_args) )
            $widget_args = array( 'number' => $widget_args );           
        $widget_args = wp_parse_args( $widget_args, array( 'number' => -1 ) );
        extract( $widget_args, EXTR_SKIP );

        $options = get_option('yelprt_widget');
            $title = $options[$number]['title'];
            $speed = $options[$number]['speed'];
            $pause = $options[$number]['pause'];
            $showitems = $options[$number]['showitems'];
            $animation = $options[$number]['animation'];
            $mousepause = $options[$number]['mousepause'];
            //$height = $options[$number]['height'];
            $direction = $options[$number]['direction'];
            $yrtunsigned_url = $options[$number]['unsigned_url'];
            $yrtconsumer_key = $options[$number]['consumer_key'];
            $yrtconsumer_secret = $options[$number]['consumer_secret'];
            $yrttoken = $options[$number]['token'];
            $yrttoken_secret = $options[$number]['token_secret'];
            echo "<!-- Start Yelp Reviews Ticker -->\n";
            echo "<link type='text/css' href='" . plugins_url( 'css/yelprt.css' , __FILE__ ) . "' rel='stylesheet'/>\n";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='" . plugins_url( 'lib/jquery.js' , __FILE__ ) . "'></script>\n";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='" . plugins_url( 'lib/jquery.vticker-min.js' , __FILE__ ) . "'></script>\n";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
            echo "  $(function(){\n";
            echo "  $('#yelprt').vTicker({ \n";
            echo "      speed: ".$speed.",\n";
            echo "      pause: ".$pause.",\n";
            echo "      animation: '".$animation."',\n";
            echo "      mousePause: ".$mousepause.",\n";
            echo "      direction: '".$direction."',\n";
            echo "      showItems: ".$showitems."\n";
            echo "  });\n";
            echo "});\n";
            echo "</script>\n";
            echo "<!-- End Yelp Reviews Ticker -->\n";
    }
?>
```

I know I still have a lot of code cleaning

Comment: Indeed you do have some code cleaning to do. :)

That is a lot of code to read. Please try to narrow it down. Is your value correct right before `update_options`? Have you checked the database to verify that the value is saved? Maybe the issue is with the retrieval. Also, you really should be using the [Widget API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API). I am surprised that those old-school widget registrations functions are not deprecated (yet).

Comment: Values get saved to the db under _options -> yelprt_widget, and sorry, for my lack of experience on wordpress, I copied and pasted parts of example code, maybe it wasn't up to date.  The problem is that when 'code' // Send Yelp API Call 'code' after that line, when I am making the call for the keys and settings it does not use the values. I can get it to print the values, but for some reason when it's withing the code it seems like the value is blank

Comment: Ok. So the problem is not what you said it was. The option does save. Your issue is with retrieval. Actually, I am not sure you answered the question. Does the API key, specifically, save?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I miss explained? sorry, yes. instead of using say $unsigned_url I actually use the URL it works. and if I print $unsigned_url it will print the actual URL... so that is where I am stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed I was using a very old "plugin template" before wordpress had the $instance call.
so people used to make their own instances, wich is what I was doing.
I've cleaned up my code and got it working.
The only problem I encountered is that my css won't work in the plugin once jQuery takes over.
But that is a different question.
here is my fix

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name:  Yelp Reviews Ticker
Plugin URI:   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/
Description:  This reviews ticker allows you to show your yelp reviews and also customize its display to your taste in a easy manner
Version:      0.5
Author:       Flavio Domeneck Jr
Author URI:   http://www.flaviotreeservice.com/ 
License: GPL2

Copyright 2013  FDJ  (email : contactflavio@gmail.com )

    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as 
    published by the Free Software Foundation.

    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
    Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/


class yrtWidget extends WP_Widget {
    function yrtWidget() {
        parent::__construct( 
            false, 
            'Yelp Reviews Ticker',
            array( 'description' => "Yelp Reviews Ticker shows your yelp reviews cleanly and pain free" ) 
        );

    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract($args);
        echo $before_widget;
        echo $before_title.$instance['title'].$after_title;

//
// Partially from
// http://non-diligent.com/articles/yelp-apiv2-php-example/
// https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/php/example.php
//

// Enter the path that the oauth library is in relation to the php file
require_once ('lib/OAuth.php');

// Set instance values
$speed = $instance['speed'];
$pause = $instance['pause'];
$showitems = $instance['showitems'];
$animation = $instance['animation'];
$mousepause = $instance['mousepause'];
$direction = $instance['direction'];
$yelp_url = $instance['yelp_url'];
$unsigned_url = $instance['unsigned_url'];
$consumer_key = $instance['consumer_key'];
$consumer_secret = $instance['consumer_secret'];
$token = $instance['token'];
$token_secret = $instance['token_secret'];

// Token object built using the OAuth library
$token = new OAuthToken($token, $token_secret);

// Consumer object built using the OAuth library
$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);

// Yelp uses HMAC SHA1 encoding
$signature_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();

// Build OAuth Request using the OAuth PHP library. Uses the consumer and token object created above.
$oauthrequest = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $token, 'GET', $unsigned_url);

// Sign the request
$oauthrequest->sign_request($signature_method, $consumer, $token);

// Get the signed URL
$signed_url = $oauthrequest->to_url();

// Send Yelp API Call
$ch = curl_init($signed_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch); // Yelp response
curl_close($ch);

// Handle Yelp response data
$response = json_decode($data);

$arr = (array) $response;



if(is_array($arr['reviews'])){
    ?>

<!-- Start Yelp Reviews Ticker -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#yelp-review-ticker').vTicker({ 
    <?
    echo "  speed: " . $instance['speed'] . ",\n";
    echo "  pause: " . $instance['pause'] . ",\n";
    echo "  animation: '" . $instance['animation'] . "',\n";
    echo "  mousePause: " . $instance['mousepause'] . ",\n";
    echo "  direction: '" . $instance['direction'] . "',\n";
    echo "  showItems: " . $instance['showitems'] . "\n";
    ?>
    });
});
</script>
<!-- End Yelp Reviews Ticker -->
<div id="yelp-review-ticker"><ul>
<? foreach($arr['reviews'] as $review){ ?>
        <li>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center; padding:5px; font-size:90%">
<? echo "               <img src=\"" . $review->user->image_url . "\" width=\"60px\"/>\n";
echo "                  <br />" . $review->user->name . "\n";
echo "                  <br /><img src=\"" . $review->rating_image_small_url . "\" />\n";
?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
<? echo "               <p>" . $review->excerpt . "</p>\n"; 
echo "                  <div style=\"text-align:right; font-size:80%;\"><a href=\"" . $instance['yelp_url'] . "\" target=\"_blank\"> " . gmdate("m/d/Y", $review->time_created) . " more at \n"; 
echo "                      <img src=\"http://s3-media1.ak.yelpcdn.com/assets/2/www/img/14f29ad24935/map/miniMapLogo.png\"/></a>\n";
?>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
<? } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<? }


echo $after_widget;

} // End function widget.


    function yrtWidget_header(){
// jQuery vTicker from
// http://www.jugbit.com/jquery-vticker-vertical-news-ticker/
        echo '
        <script type="text/javascript" src="' . plugins_url( 'lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js' , __FILE__ ) . '"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="' . plugins_url( 'lib/jquery.vticker-min.js' , __FILE__ ) . '"></script>
        <style type="text/css"  media="all" src="' . plugins_url( 'css/yelprt.css' , __FILE__ ) . '"></style>
        ';

    }

// Updates the settings.

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        return $new_instance;
    }
    function form( $instance ) { //<- set default parameters of widget
        if($instance){
            $title = $instance['title'];
            $speed = $instance['speed'];
            $pause = $instance['pause'];
            $showitems = $instance['showitems'];
            $animation = $instance['animation'];
            $mousepause = $instance['mousepause'];
            $direction = $instance['direction'];
            $yelp_url = $instance['yelp_url'];
            $unsigned_url = $instance['unsigned_url'];
            $consumer_key = $instance['consumer_key'];
            $consumer_secret = $instance['consumer_secret'];
            $token = $instance['token'];
            $token_secret = $instance['token_secret'];
        }
        else{
            $title = 'Reviews';
            $speed = '2500';
            $pause = '6000';
            $showitems = '2';
            $animation = 'fade';
            $mousepause = 'true';
            $direction = 'up';
            $yelp_url = 'http://www.yelp.com/biz/';
            $unsigned_url = 'http://api.yelp.com/v2/business/';
            $consumer_key = '';
            $consumer_secret = '';
            $token = '';
            $token_secret = '';
        }
    ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title');?>">Widget Title</label><br />
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('speed');?>">Speed</label><br />
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('speed');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('speed');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $speed; ?>"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('pause');?>">Pause</label><br />
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('pause');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('pause');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $pause; ?>"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('showitems');?>"># of reviews</label><br />
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('showitems');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('showitems');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $showitems; ?>"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('animation');?>">Fade</label><br />
            Yes <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('animation');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('animation');?>" type="radio" <?php if($animation == 'fade') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="fade"/>
            No <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('animation');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('animation');?>" type="radio" <?php if($animation == '') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value=""/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('mousepause');?>">Mouse Pause</label><br />
            Yes <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('mousepause');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('mousepause');?>" type="radio" <?php if($mousepause == 'true') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="true"/>
            No <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('mousepause');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('mousepause');?>" type="radio" <?php if($mousepause == 'false') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="false"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('direction');?>">Direction</label><br />
            Up <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('direction');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('direction');?>" type="radio" <?php if($direction == 'up') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="up"/>
            Down <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('direction');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('direction');?>" type="radio" <?php if($direction == 'down') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="down"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('yelp_url');?>">Yelp Business URL</label><br />
            http://www.yelp.com/biz/...<br />
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('yelp_url');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('yelp_url');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $yelp_url; ?>"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('unsigned_url');?>">API Business URL</label><br />
            http://api.yelp.com/v2/business/...<br />
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('unsigned_url');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('unsigned_url');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $unsigned_url; ?>"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('consumer_key');?>">Consumer Key</label><br />
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('consumer_key');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('consumer_key');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $consumer_key; ?>"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('consumer_secret');?>">Consumer Secret</label><br />
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('consumer_secret');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('consumer_secret');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $consumer_secret; ?>"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('token');?>">Token</label><br />
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('token');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('token');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $token; ?>"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('token_secret');?>">Token Secret</label><br />
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('token_secret');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('token_secret');?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $token_secret; ?>"/>
        </p>


    <?php
    } // end function form



} // end class

// Register the widget.
function yrtw_register() {
    register_widget( 'yrtWidget' );
}

add_action('wp_head', 'add_yrt_header');
    function add_yrt_header(){

        echo '
        <script type="text/javascript" src="' . plugins_url( 'lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js' , __FILE__ ) . '"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="' . plugins_url( 'lib/jquery.vticker-min.js' , __FILE__ ) . '"></script>
        <style type="text/css"  media="all" src="' . plugins_url( 'css/yelprt.css' , __FILE__ ) . '"></style>
        ';

    }

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'yrtw_register' );


?>
```

I hope it helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump($options);` right under this line-- `$options = get_option('yelprt_widget');` and tell me if `$unsigned_url` is there.

Comment: I am assuming it has populated correctly though this line: `$unsigned_url = $options[$number]['unsigned_url'];` If so, `var_dump($oauthrequest)`

Comment: I wasn't able to `var_dump($oauthrequest)` because it caused an error, but `echo $oauthrequest;` gives me the expected URL